# In VBA, looping with multiple conditions 'And' along with 'Or' conditions together by grouping them?

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a code to check for two conditions simultaneously from my data file. Currently my script works fine because its only checking for the brand name on column A. However I also want to check for the category on column B whether its a "Sun" or "Vista". 
Structurally I want something like:

```
For i = 2 to Last_row
If Cells(i,1).value = "BananaRepublic" and Cells(i, 2).value = "Sun" or "Vista" then,
   Row(i).Copy
   Worksheet(new_worksheet).Paste
```

Please note: on an average there are over 30 different brands that I need to enter in this list which need to be matched with their value on column B(Sun/Vista) and I then need to replicate this for 20 different macros each for a different combination of brand names and Sun/Optical category. Doing it individually seems very inefficient. Is there a better solution?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub StarOptical()

'Define all variables
Dim customer_name As String
Dim sheetName As String

sName = ActiveSheet.Name

'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Sort.SortFields.Clear

'Enter the Customer Name here
customer_name = "StarOptical"
Sheets.Add.Name = customer_name

'Copy same header to the new worksheet
Worksheets(sName).Rows(1).Copy
Worksheets(customer_name).Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Find the last row of the report
last_row = Worksheets(sName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


'Start the loop and scan through each row for listed brands
For i = 2 To last_row
    'Update the names of the approved brands in the line below
    If Worksheets(sName).Cells(i, 1).Value = "ADENSCO" Or Worksheets(sName).Cells(i, 1).Value = "BANANAREPUBLI" Or Worksheets(sName).Cells(i, 1).Value = "BOSS(HUB)" Then

        Worksheets(sName).Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets(customer_name).Activate
        last_row_new = Worksheets(customer_name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets(customer_name).Cells(last_row_new + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets(customer_name).Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Activate/Copy/Paste is trying to do it from an end user's perspective. You should probably learn how to do it more programmatically using the object model.

Comment: Make a Sub with two parameters (1) Brand Name to match on Col1 (2) array of values to match on ColB: you can call that sub with different combinations of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub tester()

    CreateSheet "BananaRepublic", Array("Sun", "Vista")
    'etc for other sheets

End Sub


Sub CreateSheet(sBrand As String, arrVals)

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Long, c As Range

    Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
    Set wsDest = wsSrc.Parent.Sheets.Add()

    wsDest.Name = sBrand
    wsSrc.Rows(1).Copy wsDest.Cells(1, 1)
    Set c = wsDest.Cells(2, 1)

    For i = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'match on ColA?
        If wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Value = sBrand Then
            'match on colB ?
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(wsSrc.Cells(i, 2).Value, arrVals, 0)) Then
                wsSrc.Rows(i).Copy c     'copy the row
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)   'next cell down for copy destination
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That gives me the idea.